# Python socket in java

Tags: java, python, sockets

Can a java module be modified or used within a python application when programming network socket? Is there any library for that or can jython be used for that purpose ?

Comment: Why don't you simply use python only? Why you want to mix up with java. any specific reason?

Comment: If your question is "Can I use a Java module from Python?" then how are sockets relevant?

Comment: i heard that java is efficient for socket programming, that is why i want to use that with in the python application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try python modules that allow to access java classes *dynamically* such as [Py4j](http://py4j.sourceforge.net/index.html) and [JPype](http://jpype.sourceforge.net/).